# choosing map over list in the method

Tags: java

I have a method and its return type is of list but that method inside make 3 different list based upon certain conditions and feed thos list but at last since the return type of that list I could not return these 3 diffent list since at some point I need an acces to these 3 different list , I think these is not the right approach instead I would thinking  to go for a map in which I would create a  key and associate the 3 different list with them, please advise

```
   public List<ghjObject> getabcObjectslistcount(String abcIdentifier)
    {

        List<ghjObject> abcfulioaObjects = new ArrayList <ghjObject>();
        List<ghjObject> deffulioaObjects = new ArrayList <ghjObject>();
        List<ghjObject> exsettlement = new ArrayList <ghjObject>();
        List<ghjObject> successfulabcsettlement = new ArrayList <ghjObject>();


        List<ghjObject> abcFeedObjects = futuresFeedHome.getabcFeedObjects(abcIdentifier);


        int failureabcfeed = 0;
        int failuredefsettlement =0;
        int sucessabcsettlement =0; 

        if (abcFeedObjects !=null  && abcFeedObjects.size()>0)
        {
             for (ghjObject f : abcFeedObjects) 
                {

                 if ("INVALID".equalsIgnoreCase(f.getStatus()) )
                 {
                     deffulioaObjects.add(f) ;
                     failurecounterioafeed++;

                 }

                 abcfulioaObjects.add(f);       

                }

             for (ghjObject f : abcfulioaObjects) 
             {
             Settlement settlement = settlementHome.findByID(f.getSettlementId());


             if ("ytrQueue".equalsIgnoreCase(settlement.getCurrentWFQueue()) || "yds".equalsIgnoreCase(settlement.getCurrentWFQueue()) )
             exsettlement.add(f);
             failuredefsettlement++;            



             if ("wgm".equalsIgnoreCase(settlement.getCurrentWFQueue()) || "yjm".equalsIgnoreCase(settlement.getCurrentWFQueue() ))
                 {
                 successfulabcsettlement.add(f);
                 sucessabcsettlement++;
                 }
    }
    }
        return abcFeedObjects;
    }
```

folks please advise basically I was looking for map implementation if somebody could plese advise how map is benefial that would be a great
please advise for map implementation

Comment: Why not return a `List<List<ghjObject>>`?

Comment: @drewmore couldn't get it completely, please explain in detail

Comment: Why not have your method return a list of lists: `public List<List<ghjObject>> getabcObjectslistcount(String abcIdentifier)`

Comment: @drewmore could you please make changes in my above code so that I can grasp more

Answer (score 2):

This really should just have been a comment, but since you asked for it:

```
 public List<List<ghjObject>> getabcObjectslistcount(String abcIdentifier)
{
    List<List<ghjObject>> toReturn = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ghjObject>>();
    List<ghjObject> abcfulioaObjects = new ArrayList <ghjObject>();
    List<ghjObject> deffulioaObjects = new ArrayList <ghjObject>();
    List<ghjObject> exsettlement = new ArrayList <ghjObject>();
    List<ghjObject> successfulabcsettlement = new ArrayList <ghjObject>();
    List<ghjObject> abcFeedObjects = futuresFeedHome.getabcFeedObjects(abcIdentifier);
    toReturn.add(abcfulioaObjects);
    toReturn.add(deffulioaObjects);
    toReturn.add(exsettlement);
    toReturn.add(successfulabcsettlement);
    toReturn.add(abcFeedObjects);
    ...
    //execute the rest of your code, add whatever you need to to those lists, then

    return toReturn;
}
```

I don't know enough about your use case to tell you whether this is a good design, but it accomplishes what you said you need to accomplish - which is to return several lists from a method in order to interact with them elsewhere. Its basically the same idea you had - returning a map with several lists as values - but, if you don't need the added Map functionality, this is simpler.

EDIT: You access the lists returned in the same ways you access the elements of any list: `returned.get(index);`, assuming you have named the list of lists "returned" (which you shouldn't, obviously...). This assumes your use case enables you to easily track which list will be at which index (based on what order they were put into the list). If not, you should use a map with meaningful names as keys with the lists as values.

Comment: You probably want to add to `toReturn` after the actual processing?

Comment: @drewmore than please also advise how could we retireve the individual list fro the set of lists

Comment: @zEro - no, it doesn't make a difference.